# Efficient chain merge in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I found that straightforward chain merging with pandas library is quite inefficient when you merge a lot of datasets with a big number of columns by the same column.

The root of the problem is the same as when we join a lot of str's dumb way:

```
joined = reduce(lambda a + b, str_list)
```

Instead of:

```
joined = ''.join(str_list)
```

Doing chain merge we're copying the dataset many times (in my case almost 100 times) instead of just filling columns from several datasets at once or in order.

Is there is some efficient way (= with linear complexity by the number of sets) to chain merge by the same column a lot of datasets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a list of your dataframes `dfs`:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, ... , dfn]
```

you can join them using panda's [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects) function which as far as I can tell is faster than chaining merge. `concat` only joins dataframes based on an index (not a column) but with a little pre-processing you can simulate a `merge` operation.

First replace the index of each of your dataframes in `dfs` with the column you want to merge on. Lets say you want to merge on column `"A"`:

```
dfs = [df.set_index("A", drop=True) for df in dfs]
```

Note that this **will** overwrite the previous indices (merge would do this anyway) so you might want to save these indices somewhere (if you are going to need them later for some reason).

Now we can use concat which will essentially merge on the index (which is **actually your column**!!)

```
merged = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, keys=range(len(dfs)), join='outer', copy=False)
```

The `join=` argument can either be `'inner'` or `'outer'` (default). The `copy=` argument keeps `concat` from making unnecessary copies of your dataframes.

You can then either leave `"A"` as the index or you can make it back into a column by doing:

```
merged.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
```

The `keys=` argument is optional and assigns a key value to each dataframe (in this case I gave it a range of integers but you could give them other labels if you want). This allows you to access columns from the original dataframes. So if you wanted to get the columns that correspond to the 20th dataframe in `dfs` you can call:

```
merged[20]
```

Without the `keys=` argument it can get confusing which rows are from which dataframes, especially if they have the same column names.

I'm still not entirely sure if `concat` runs in linear time but it is definitely faster than chaining `merge`:

using ipython's %timeit on lists of randomly generated dataframes (lists of 10, 100 and 1000 dataframes):

```
def merge_with_concat(dfs, col):                                             
    dfs = [df.set_index(col, drop=True) for df in dfs]
    merged = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, keys=range(len(dfs)), join='outer', copy=False)
    return merged

dfs10 = [pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame() for i in range(10)] 
dfs100 = [pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame() for i in range(100)] 
dfs1000 = [pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame() for i in range(1000)] 

%timeit reduce(lambda df1, df2: df1.merge(df2, on="A", how='outer'), dfs10)
10 loops, best of 3: 45.8 ms per loop
%timeit merge_with_concat(dfs10,"A")
100 loops, best of 3: 11.7 ms per loop

%timeit merge_with_concat(dfs100,"A")
10 loops, best of 3: 139 ms per loop
%timeit reduce(lambda df1, df2: df1.merge(df2, on="A", how='outer'), dfs100)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.55 s per loop

%timeit merge_with_concat(dfs1000,"A")
1 loop, best of 3: 9.67 s per loop
%timeit reduce(lambda df1, df2: df1.merge(df2, on="A", how='outer'), dfs1000)
# I killed it after about 5 minutes so the other one is definitely faster
```

Comment: wouldn't `dfs = (df.set_index(col, drop=True) for df in dfs)` be more memory efficient since it's a generator

Comment: @muon yes, great catch! I ran a couple of benchmarks with the `dfs1000` set after changing it to a generator and it seems to run about 2.5 seconds faster on my system (7.1 seconds down from 9.6).  Note that if you want to make this change you should call the generator something other than `dfs` since you still need to get the length of `dfs` (number of dataframes to merge) for the `keys` argument in `pd.concat` and generators don't have a length.