# How to efficiently join/merge/concatenate large data frame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

**The aim** is to create a big data frame on which I can them perform operations such as average each row across the columns etc.

**The problem** is that as the data frame increases, the speed for each iteration increases as well, so I cannot finish my computation.

**Notes:** my `df` has only two columns, where `col1` is unnecessary, hence why I join on it. `col1` is a string and `col2` is a float. The number of rows is 3k. Below is an example:

```
folder_paths    float
folder/Path     1.12630137
folder/Path2    1.067517426
folder/Path3    1.06443264
folder/Path4    1.049119625
folder/Path5    1.039635769
```

**Question** Any ideas on how this code can be made more efficient and where are the bottlenecks? Also, I am unsure if `merge` is the way to go.

**Current ideas** One solution that I was considering was to per-allocate the memory and specify the column types: `col1` is a string and `col2` is a float.

```
df = pd.DataFrame() # create an empty data frame

for i in range(1000):
    if i is 0:
        df = generate_new_df(arg1, arg2)
    else:
        df = pd.merge(df, generate_new_df(arg1, arg2), on='col1', how='outer')
```

I have also tried to use `pd.concat` as well, but the results are very similar: an increase in time after each iteration

```
df = pd.concat([df, get_os_is_from_folder(pnlList, sampleSize, randomState)], axis=1)
```

**result with pd.concat**

```
run 1
time 0.34s
run 2    
time 0.34s
run 3    
time 0.32s
run 4    
time 0.33s
run 5    
time 0.42s
run 6    
time 0.41s
run 7    
time 0.45s
run 8    
time 0.46s
run 9    
time 0.54s
run 10   
time 0.58s
run 11   
time 0.73s
run 12   
time 0.72s
run 13   
time 0.79s
run 14   
time 0.87s
run 15   
time 0.95s
run 16   
time 1.06s
run 17   
time 1.19s
run 18   
time 1.24s
run 19   
time 1.37s
run 20   
time 1.57s
run 21   
time 1.68s
run 22   
time 1.93s
run 23   
time 1.86s
run 24   
time 1.96s
run 25   
time 2.11s
run 26   
time 2.32s
run 27   
time 2.42s
run 28   
time 2.57s
```

Using a `dfList` and `pd.concat` of the list yielded similar results. Below is the code & results.

```
dfList=[]
for i in range(1000):
    dfList.append(generate_new_df(arg1, arg2))

df = pd.concat(dfList, axis=1)
```

**Results:**

```
run 1 took 0.35 sec.
run 2 took 0.26 sec.
run 3 took 0.3 sec.
run 4 took 0.33 sec.
run 5 took 0.45 sec.
run 6 took 0.49 sec.
run 7 took 0.54 sec.
run 8 took 0.51 sec.
run 9 took 0.51 sec.
run 10 took 1.06 sec.
run 11 took 1.74 sec.
run 12 took 1.47 sec.
run 13 took 1.25 sec.
run 14 took 1.04 sec.
run 15 took 1.26 sec.
run 16 took 1.35 sec.
run 17 took 1.7 sec.
run 18 took 1.73 sec.
run 19 took 6.03 sec.
run 20 took 1.63 sec.
run 21 took 1.93 sec.
run 22 took 1.84 sec.
run 23 took 2.25 sec.
run 24 took 2.65 sec.
run 25 took 6.84 sec.
run 26 took 2.88 sec.
run 27 took 2.58 sec.
run 28 took 2.81 sec.
run 29 took 2.84 sec.
run 30 took 2.99 sec.
run 31 took 3.12 sec.
run 32 took 3.48 sec.
run 33 took 3.35 sec.
run 34 took 3.6 sec.
run 35 took 4.0 sec.
run 36 took 4.41 sec.
run 37 took 4.88 sec.
run 38 took 4.92 sec.
run 39 took 4.78 sec.
run 40 took 5.02 sec.
run 41 took 5.32 sec.
run 42 took 5.31 sec.
run 43 took 5.78 sec.
run 44 took 5.77 sec.
run 45 took 6.15 sec.
run 46 took 6.4 sec.
run 47 took 6.84 sec.
run 48 took 7.08 sec.
run 49 took 7.48 sec.
run 50 took 7.91 sec.
```

Comment: Why are you merging 1000 times?

Comment: Well, each new data frame is from a separate csv file, so I generate a df with my needed information and there are about 1k or 10k such csv files.

Comment: What is the format of these files and why do they need to be merged back as opposed to concatenated?

Comment: As I have written in Question, I am unsure if merge is the best way to go, so whichever one is quicker and gets the job done is fine.
The format is: colum1 (string) and colume2(float) with about 3k rows each

Comment: check out this answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40568957/5992438).  It simulates merge by `concat`enating in batches which is more efficient. (disclaimer: this was my answer)

Comment: @bunji I checked it earlier and albeit it was helpful, the first time when I did it like so (i.e. create a list of DFs and then concatenate). The list creation is what was taking a long time. So long that I could not get to the concat part. Any idea why that may be?

Comment: It might depend on a few things, can you show your code for your `generate_new_df` function and maybe give the average size of an single dataframe (2 columns but how many rows?). Also, what are the operations that you want to perform on your dataframe once it has been merged because it might be possible to do without needing to merge in the first place.

Comment: @bunji I have updated this info in the question now

Comment: You're not doing anything differently. pd.concat should go outside of the for loop. appending to the list is what goes inside the for loop.

Comment: I did just that now and the results are arguably the same and there is no jump in speed. I will upload the updated code now and the results.

Comment: why do you have multiple runs in the list case? you should generate _all_ dataframes you plan on concatenating into a list, and only do a concat once. this is a similar problem to string `+=` vs. `join`....

Comment: @CorleyBrigman Do you mean like the final example that I have provided?

Comment: the code looks right... but the output is still printing 'run1', 'run2', etc. - you need to move the `pd.concat` outside _that_ loop...

Comment: @CorleyBrigman I have moved the `pd.concat` outside. Please check the final example between the results

Comment: where's the loop where run1, run2, etc. are printed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is still a little unclear exactly what your problem is but I'm going to assume that the main bottleneck is that you are trying to load lots of dataframes into a list all at once and you're running into memory/paging issues. With this is mind, here is an approach which might help but you will have to test it yourself since I don't have access to your `generate_new_df` function or your data.

The approach is to use a variation on the `merge_with_concat` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40568957/5992438), and merge smaller numbers of your dataframes together initially and then merge them all together at once.

For example, if you have 1000 dataframes, you can merge 100 together at a time to give you 10 big dataframes and then merge those final 10 together as a last step.  This should ensure that you don't have a list of dataframes that is too big at any one point.

You can use the two functions below (I'm assuming your `generate_new_df` function takes a file name as one of its arguments) and do something like:

```
def chunk_dfs(file_names, chunk_size):
    """" yields n dataframes at a time where n == chunksize """
    dfs = []
    for f in file_names:
        dfs.append(generate_new_df(f))
        if len(dfs) == chunk_size:
            yield dfs
            dfs  = []
    if dfs:
        yield dfs


def merge_with_concat(dfs, col):                                             
    dfs = (df.set_index(col, drop=True) for df in dfs)
    merged = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, join='outer', copy=False)
    return merged.reset_index(drop=False)

col_name = "name_of_column_to_merge_on"
file_names = ['list/of', 'file/names', ...]
chunk_size = 100

merged = merge_with_concat((merge_with_concat(dfs, col_name) for dfs in chunk_dfs(file_names, chunk_size)), col_name)
```