# Concat list of dataframes in pandas not working because the list is too long

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, concatenation

I am importing a large list of JSON files. They come from one folder for each year.
The files are properly imported, and stored as dataframes in a list. My plan was to concatenate the list and export as one CSV for each year. The problem is that concatenate is not working because the list of df is too long (it works when I try with few files). I think I should find a way to make a list for each folder in order to concatenate each list and then exporting, or find a way to concatenate only the df in the list that have the same year (every df has a column with the year value). I can't do neither, so I need help.

My code looks like this:

```py
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Local\\hs')  
rootdir = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Local\\hs'

data_df = []
files_notloading=[]
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(subdir, file))
        if 'json' in os.path.join(subdir, file):
            try:
                with open(os.path.join(subdir, file),'r') as f:
                    data = json.loads(f.read())
                    if not data['search']:
                        data['search'] = [{'R': 0}]
            # Normalizing data
                df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['search'],
                                   meta =['month', 'type',
                                          'day','year'],errors='ignore')
                data_df.append(df)
            except: files_notloading.append(file)

data_df = pd.concat(data_df)
files_notloading = pd.DataFrame(files_notloading)

for year in data_df['year'].unique():
    file_name = '/Users/User/Documents/data/hs_{0}.csv'.format(year) 
    data_df[data_df['year'] == year].to_csv(file_name, index= False)
    
files_notloading.to_csv(path_or_buf='/Users/User/Documents/data/filesnotloading_hs.csv',index= False)
```

Comment: Check out this answer regarding concatenating a large number of dataframes. Essentially the workaround is to concatenate subsets of dataframes into larger dataframes and then concatenate the larger dataframes into your final:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40568957/5992438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a way to make a list for each folder in order to concatenate each list and then exporting.

code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import json
import os.path
import os

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Local\\hs')  
working_dir = "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Local\\hs"
output_dir = "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Local\\hs"

files_notloading=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(working_dir):
    file_list = []
    df_list=[]
    for filename in files:
        print(os.path.join(root,filename))
        if filename.endswith('.json'):
            file_list.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    for file in file_list:
        try:
            with open(file,'r') as f:
                data = json.loads(f.read())
                if not data['search']:
                    data['search'] = [{'R': 0}]
                df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['search'],
                                       meta =['month','type', 'day','year'],errors='ignore')
                df_list.append(df)
        except: files_notloading.append(file)
    if df_list:
        final_df = pd.concat(df_list)
        final_file = 'hs_{0}.csv'.format(final_df['year'].iloc[0])
        final_df.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir, final_file),index=False)

files_notloading = pd.DataFrame(files_notloading,columns =['file'])
files_notloading.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir, 'hs_files_notloading.csv'),index= False)
```